# Run and refresh PHP server using Gulp

Tags: php, refresh, reload, gulp, server

How can I use gulp to run and refresh server on existing host and port which use PHP? Apache/PHP runs on http://localhost:80

```
gulp.task('connect', function () {
    var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
    var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
    var app = require('connect')()
            .use(require('connect-livereload')({port: 35729}))
            .use(serveStatic('dist'))
            .use(serveStatic('app'))
            .use(serveIndex('app'));

    require('http').createServer(app)
            .listen(8888)
            .on('listening', function () {
                console.log('Web server start on port 8888');
            });
});

gulp.task('serve', ['connect'], function () {
    require('opn')('http://localhost:8888');
});
```

This code works fine. If I change something (like js, css etc..) browser is refreshed. This if for port 8888. But when I want to use web server on which PHP is running so in my case port 80 - it fails.
I want to automatically refresh page after I change some styles or javascript etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gulp-livereload` to reload asset files just connected with the livereload browser extension.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-livereload

The gulp reload task does not require actually managing the server, just access to the browser.

Comment: I have already try this, this not work. I run PHP on port 80 so browser must open on localhost:80 and not localhost:8000 or other port often used like 8888 or 9000. If you try at port 80 then this livereload (also extension to Google Chrome) doesn't work. What do you have set that this livereload work with PHP on port 80? Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that if I try to listen at port 80 I got error EADDRINUSE - this is because this port already use my webserver (Apache with PHP).

Comment: Livereload does NOT affect any ports. It will work with php if you use this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei and this: https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload

Comment: Yes it works with livereload extension to Google Chrome. Thanks.